# Consulta funciona en PHPMyAdmin pero no en el script PHP

Tags: php, mysql

La consulta:

```
SELECT
`morel_asigntura`.`asignatura`,
`morel_asignaturas_ei`.`nombre_ei`,
`morel_asignaturas_ei`.`activo_ei`,
(CASE 
WHEN `morel_asignaturas_ei`.`activo_ei` =0
THEN "0"
WHEN `morel_asignaturas_ei`.`activo_ei` =1
THEN "1"
ELSE "2"
END) as valor,
`morel_jefatura`.`departamento`,
`morel_jefatura`.`activo_jefatura`
FROM `morel_jefatura_materia`
LEFT JOIN `morel_asigntura`
ON `morel_asigntura`.`id` = `morel_jefatura_materia`.`id_asignatura`
LEFT JOIN `morel_asignaturas_ei`
ON `morel_asignaturas_ei`.`id_asignatura` = `morel_asigntura`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `morel_jefatura`
ON `morel_jefatura`.`id` = `morel_jefatura_materia`.`id_jefatura`
HAVING valor >0
AND `morel_jefatura`.`activo_jefatura` = '1'
order by `morel_jefatura`.`departamento`
```

Funciona cuando la hago en PHPMyAdmin pero no en el script:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Jefatura Docente</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Jefatura Docente</h1>
<?php
@ $db =  mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "iunaorg_admin", "521002", "iunaorg_morel"); /*Conectamos a la base de datos usando
  la funcion mysql_pconnect(). Guardamos la conexion a la base de datos en una variable $db 
  Si queremos que un error de php no aparezca en pantalla le agregamos @ */

  if (!$db)
  {
     echo "Error: No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos.  Por favor, prueba de nuevo más tarde.";
  }
  else{echo "Te conectaste!!!!";
  }
$consulta = "
SELECT
`morel_asigntura`.`asignatura`,
`morel_asignaturas_ei`.`nombre_ei`,
`morel_asignaturas_ei`.`activo_ei`,
(CASE 
WHEN `morel_asignaturas_ei`.`activo_ei` =0
THEN "0"
WHEN `morel_asignaturas_ei`.`activo_ei` =1
THEN "1"
ELSE "2"
END) as valor,
`morel_jefatura`.`departamento`,
`morel_jefatura`.`activo_jefatura`
FROM `morel_jefatura_materia`
LEFT JOIN `morel_asigntura`
ON `morel_asigntura`.`id` = `morel_jefatura_materia`.`id_asignatura`
LEFT JOIN `morel_asignaturas_ei`
ON `morel_asignaturas_ei`.`id_asignatura` = `morel_asigntura`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `morel_jefatura`
ON `morel_jefatura`.`id` = `morel_jefatura_materia`.`id_jefatura`
HAVING valor >0
AND `morel_jefatura`.`activo_jefatura` = '1'
order by `morel_jefatura`.`departamento`
";
echo "verificacion!";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Devuelve una hoja en blanco. El problema está en

```
(CASE 
WHEN `morel_asignaturas_ei`.`activo_ei` =0
THEN "0"
WHEN `morel_asignaturas_ei`.`activo_ei` =1
THEN "1"
ELSE "2"
END) as valor,
```

Pero no sé cómo resolverlo.

Comment: que error te devuelve?, creo que debes quitar las `

Comment: no es (CASE 
WHEN morel_asignaturas_ei.activo_ei =0
THEN "0"
WHEN morel_asignaturas_ei.activo_ei =1
THEN "1"
ELSE "2"
END **CASE**) as valor,

Answer (score 3):

Siempre tenemos este tipo de error estas utilizando **comillas dobles** dentro de tu sentencia, solo debes remplazarlas por **comillas simples**

Dentro del **PHP** toma como inicio de tu **sentencia** desde la apertura de tu **comilla doble** y lo cierra donde encuentra otro, por eso tu consulta finalizaba en el **case**, si vamos a utilizar **comillas dobes** al inicio se recomienda poner **dentro comillas** simples, no obstante puede ser de forma inversa abres con **comillas simples** y adentro **comillas dobles**

```
"
SELECT
`morel_asigntura`.`asignatura`,
`morel_asignaturas_ei`.`nombre_ei`,
`morel_asignaturas_ei`.`activo_ei`,
(CASE 
WHEN `morel_asignaturas_ei`.`activo_ei` =0
THEN '0'
WHEN `morel_asignaturas_ei`.`activo_ei` =1
THEN '1'
ELSE '2'
END) as valor,
`morel_jefatura`.`departamento`,
`morel_jefatura`.`activo_jefatura`
FROM `morel_jefatura_materia`
LEFT JOIN `morel_asigntura`
ON `morel_asigntura`.`id` = `morel_jefatura_materia`.`id_asignatura`
LEFT JOIN `morel_asignaturas_ei`
ON `morel_asignaturas_ei`.`id_asignatura` = `morel_asigntura`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `morel_jefatura`
ON `morel_jefatura`.`id` = `morel_jefatura_materia`.`id_jefatura`
HAVING valor >0
AND `morel_jefatura`.`activo_jefatura` = '1'
order by `morel_jefatura`.`departamento`
"
```

Comment: Funciono!! Muchas gracias

Comment: Espero cierres la pregunta con un voto a favor (Y)

Comment: @alberto entonces márcala como solución y un voto a favor tampoco vendría mal. Aunque sería bueno que Iván explicase por qué las comillas no funcionan en PHP y sí en PHPMyAdmin

Comment: @a-cedano, el motivo por el que funciona en PHPMyAdmin y no en PHP esta explicado en la respuesta de ivan-more-flores.